# Why it is not possible to use the ... syntax in expressions?

Tags: rust

I'm trying understand the `...` syntax. Consider the following program:

```
fn how_many(x: i32) -> &'static str {
    match x {
        0 => "no oranges",
        1 => "an orange",
        2 | 3 => "two or three oranges",
        9...11 => "approximately 10 oranges",
        _ => "few oranges",
    }
}

fn pattern_matching() {
    for x in 0..13 {
        println!("{} : I have {} ", x, how_many(x));
    }
}

fn main() {
    // println!("{:?}", (2...6));
    pattern_matching();
}
```

In the above program, the `9...11` used in pattern matching compiles fine. 
When I try to use the same in like `println!("{:?}", (2...6));` I get compilation error:

```
error: `...` syntax cannot be used in expressions
  --> src/main.rs:18:24
   |
18 |     println!("{:?}", (2...6));
   |                        ^^^
   |
   = help: Use `..` if you need an exclusive range (a < b)
   = help: or `..=` if you need an inclusive range (a <= b)
```

I'm trying to understand why it is not possible to use within `println`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the same reason that you cannot use `&*$#` in expressions: it's not allowed by Rust's grammar. [Rust decided to use different syntax for inclusive ranges](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237). If you really care about the complete details, you can go read all 350+ comments on that issue.

The [TL;DR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237#issuecomment-304145654):

- No particular syntax was liked by everyone
- `...` is too close to a typo of `..`
- `...` in patterns is already stabilized and must be supported forever, but it will be deprecated at some point and `..=` will be preferred for that as well.

The error message tells you the appropriate syntax to use instead:

> ```
>    = help: Use `..` if you need an exclusive range (a < b)
>    = help: or `..=` if you need an inclusive range (a <= b)
> ```

```
fn how_many(x: i32) -> &'static str {
    match x {
        0 => "no oranges",
        1 => "an orange",
        2 | 3 => "two or three oranges",
        9..=11 => "approximately 10 oranges",
        _ => "few oranges",
    }
}

fn pattern_matching() {
    for x in 0..13 {
        println!("{} : I have {} ", x, how_many(x));
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", 2..=6);
    pattern_matching();
}
```