# What's the difference between a range literal and a range pattern (e.g. between `...` and `..=`)?

Tags: rust

The [Operators and Symbols](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) appendix of the Rust Book lists two operators which are both right-inclusive ranges:

| Operator | Example | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `..=` | `..=expr`, `expr..=expr` | Right-inclusive range literal |
| `...` | `expr...expr` | In a pattern: inclusive range pattern |

What is the difference between these two operators? Or, phrased differently, what is the difference between a range *literal* and a range *pattern*?

'In a pattern' suggests that `expr...expr` must be used in a match expression and `expr..=expr` should not be. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *pattern* is something that can be used to test if a value is a certain shape. A *literal* is a piece of source code that creates a value. For discoverability purposes, some literals and patterns look similar to each other, to indicate how they are related.

Rust 1.0 allowed using `...` in a pattern, so that syntax is still allowed today for backwards compatibility:

```rust
match 42 {
    1...100 => println!("Just right"),
    _ => println!("No good"),
}
```

However, Rust 1.0 did not stabilize using `...` as a literal. After much bikeshedding, we decided that `..=` was better syntax for an inclusive range. That syntax is what was stabilized in Rust 1.26 as the literal and it was also added as a pattern.

New code should prefer `..=` for patterns. The compiler even suggests updating the usage of `...` in patterns:

```
warning: `...` range patterns are deprecated
 --> src/main.rs:3:10
  |
3 |         1...100 => println!("Just right"),
  |          ^^^ help: use `..=` for an inclusive range
  |
```

It is [proposed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/83213) that this warning will be an error in edition 2021.

The documentation could be updated to indicate that `..=` may also be used in patterns and is the preferred syntax over `...`.

See also:

- [How do I include the end value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698191/155423)
- [What is the ..= (dot dot equals) operator in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52932572/155423)
- [Why it is not possible to use the ... syntax in expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49834574/155423)

Answer (score 4):

This documentation's specific part is obsolete.

Inclusive range patterns were originally written `...` but were changed because this wasn't easy to decipher.

[Inclusive range patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#matching-ranges-of-values-with-) now have the same syntax than right inclusive range literals, that is `..=`.

See [Tracking issue for ..= inclusive ranges originally ...](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237)

Obviously some parts of the books and docs still need to be updated. I made [a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/pull/2714) to change the table you noticed.